# Having issues running a script via cgi in lighttpd

Tags: shell, cgi, sh, lighttpd

I have the following piece in my config file:

```
cgi.assign = ( ".sh" => "" )

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/urlpath/" {
  $HTTP["querystring"] =~ "cams=on" {
    cgi.assign = ( "" => "/scriptpath/CamsOn" )
  }
  $HTTP["querystring"] =~ "cams=off" {
    cgi.assign = ( "" => "/scriptpath/CamsOff" )
  }
  url.redirect = ( "^/urlpath/" => "http://somewebsite" )
}
```

I have the cgi module loaded:

```
server.modules              = (
                                "mod_redirect",
                                "mod_access",
                                "mod_cgi",
                                "mod_accesslog" )
```

Now "CamsOn" and "CamsOff" are shebanged shell scripts.  To be honest I had done this before and had it working but my server crashed and I lost my configs.  For some reason I can't figure for the life of me how to get it working. I do the redirect so I don't have to actually create the "urlpath" page.  The redirect works fine inside the $HTTP["url"] piece, and I've even tested the querystring portion by nesting a redirect inside that just takes it to google.com;  urlpath/?cams=on sent me to google accordingly.

What am I doing wrong?

Update:

I was to get it to work using

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/urlpath/" {
  $HTTP["querystring"] =~ "cams=on" {
    cgi.assign = ( "" => "/scriptpath/CamsOn" )
  }
  $HTTP["querystring"] =~ "cams=off" {
    cgi.assign = ( "" => "/scriptpath/CamsOff" )
  }
}
```

I'm thinking that the redirect was getting parsed first, so when the address changed, it no longer fit the URL and querystring comparisons. Can I change this?  The idea is to make the urlpath dynamic and updated in the conf file dynamically.  This is why I have the redirect send you to another address. This way I also don't need to do html editing or create additional folders.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

a) did not make backups

b) did not make backups

c) did not make backups

d) did not look in your own stackoverflow post history

See [Can't figure out how to receive http requests using lighttpd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296141/cant-figure-out-how-to-receive-http-requests-using-lighttpd)

If you want to reduce the number of places you edit in your config file, you can assign a value to a variable in lighttpd.conf and use the variable in lighttpd.conf.  See `var.*` in
https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_Configuration

`var.camsurlpath = "/urlpath/"
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^" + var.camsurlpath {
    ...
}`